# Best way to get thousands of IPs bound to a NIC in Windows 2008 and 2003?

Tags: windows, ip, ip-address, wmi

I had setup a small application that uses WMI to setup a nic with multiple IPs. Does someone know of a better way of doing this once we start unsing thousands of IPs on a single nic? I amnot much of a network engineer or DNS guy. I want to mkae it easy for someone to import the IPs all at once.

Comment: Why do you need thousands of IP addresses assigned to a single NIC?

Comment: Are you a sysadmin at a mental hospital? I'm dying to find out why you think you want to do this? If I remember correctly W2K8 can only have 255 NICs/IPs.

Comment: Sounds a little crazy to need thousands of IP's against a single NIC. Looking forward to finding out the reasoning behind this too.

Comment: @Chopper & @Zoredache, considering he's asked questions about multiple IPs for IIS in the past, I'm thinking this is for some really misconfigured IIS installation.

Comment: @Chris, maybe one IP per image/file :)

Comment: Well we inherited a block of 2000 IPs (/21) and have one server. Like I said I am not an expert in any of this and more of a developer. Any advice is certainly helpful. They want to host multiple sites on the server and allow their users multiple IPs per site. If there is a limit, that is good to know.

Comment: According to this post the limitation was removed in 2003 and I think it was only a GUI limitation: http://www.winvistatips.com/maximum-ip-addresses-windows-2003-server-t714693.html

Comment: I used to have a BSD box with 64 IPs going to it for web hosting.  Then they invented "VirtualHosts" and I was able to collapse it down to 1 IP.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work for you, especially the for loop at the bottom.

http://www.nthelp.com/w2k3/to_add_a_bunch_of_ip_addresses.htm

```
netsh in ip add address "Local Area Connection" 10.0.0.2 255.0.0.0
netsh in ip add address "Local Area Connection" 10.0.0.3 255.0.0.0
netsh in ip add address "Local Area Connection" 10.0.0.4 255.0.0.0

- or - 

for  /L %a in (1,1,254) do netsh in ip add address "Local Area Connection" 10.0.0.%a 255.255.255.0
```

Also, remember to use two percent signs instead of just one inside of a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Right, thanks for the clarification. Firstly there's absolutely no reason to have a single IP per website (use virtual sites in your web server of choice) and even if you did want to you should just let your router do the 2000-into-1-or-more (called NATing by the way) thing anyway. I can't stress this enough but you need a designer/sysadmin to do this for you if you're at this stage, I mean no offence but the two skill sets are wildly different.